# Product on sale doesnt go back to original price woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, product

I need assistance with products (woocommerce) that are set up for a sale. For selected products, we set a sale price, start date and an end date for the sale. Unfortunately, some products do not return to their original price when the promotion end date has passed – some products do, while others remain on sale. It’s as if the change didn’t get applied. How should I proceed to ensure that all products return to their original price when the promotion end date is reached? We have a total of over 2500 products.

Thank you for your response.

I belive it has something to do with wc_scheduled_sales() cron event (timed every day at 1:00:00)

function wc_scheduled_sales() {
$data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );

```
// Sales which are due to start.
$product_ids = $data_store->get_starting_sales();
if ( $product_ids ) {
    do_action( 'wc_before_products_starting_sales', $product_ids );
    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( $product ) {
            $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();

            if ( $sale_price ) {
                $product->set_price( $sale_price );
                $product->set_date_on_sale_from( '' );
            } else {
                $product->set_date_on_sale_to( '' );
                $product->set_date_on_sale_from( '' );
            }

            $product->save();
        }
    }
    do_action( 'wc_after_products_starting_sales', $product_ids );

    WC_Cache_Helper::get_transient_version( 'product', true );
    delete_transient( 'wc_products_onsale' );
}

// Sales which are due to end.
$product_ids = $data_store->get_ending_sales();
if ( $product_ids ) {
    do_action( 'wc_before_products_ending_sales', $product_ids );
    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( $product ) {
            $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
            $product->set_price( $regular_price );
            $product->set_sale_price( '' );
            $product->set_date_on_sale_to( '' );
            $product->set_date_on_sale_from( '' );
            $product->save();
        }
    }
    do_action( 'wc_after_products_ending_sales', $product_ids );

    WC_Cache_Helper::get_transient_version( 'product', true );
    delete_transient( 'wc_products_onsale' );
}
```

}

Is it possible to run this again at 2:00:00 every day for example to ensure every products gets to original price?